# Sqlite full text search

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Assume there is a block of message 'A'

and there is the database 'B'

I'm trying to **full text search** 'A' to see if there is a match in 'B'.

I already know how match works, such as:

```
SELECT title, body FROM pages WHERE pages MATCH 'something*';
```

But this is just for one single target 'something*' , how can I match each target in database 'B'?

It's almost impossible to spam the select sentence tons of time.

Comment: try this: `SELECT title, body FROM pages WHERE pages LIKE '%something%';`

Comment: When you say "block" and "database", do you actually mean "table"?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your problem and what you have. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT title, body FROM pages WHERE pages LIKE "%something%"

This search should be at a column level according to your question, where pages column will be containing your queried text.